# How to select case query in sequelize?

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I have a sql query:

```
SELECT field1, field2,
  CASE
    WHEN field1=1 THEN 'a'
    ELSE 'b'
  END 
  AS field3
FROM test
```

and I want to implement it with `sequelizejs` ,

```
const params = {
  attributes: //DO SELECT CASE,
};

yield Model.findAll(params);
```

Can anyone help me? Thank you.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

For the people that are still looking for this answer

```
Model.findAll({
  attributes: [[models.sequelize.literal('CASE WHEN "field1" = true THEN 55 ELSE 23 END'), 'field3']]
}
```

or

```
Model.findAll({
  attributes: { include: [[models.sequelize.literal('CASE WHEN "field1" = true THEN 55 ELSE 23 END'), 'field3']]}
}
```

So in my example when field1 is true it will return 55 else 23. This will generate a query like

```
SELECT CASE WHEN "field1" THEN 55 ELSE 23 END AS "field3" FROM "models"
```

For more information you can look in the documentation
http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/querying/#attributes